# Equivalent of thermal insulation for odor/smell?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

*Thermal insulation* expresses the capacity of a material or structure to prevent heat from being transferred from one location in space to another (other definitions exist). *Thermal* is an adjective.

The equivalent for sound is simply *sound insulation*, though I didn't find *sound* (as a vibration of the air) as being defined (in a dictionary) as an adjective, but it is here, isn't it?

What is the equivalent of *thermal insulation* for odor? Simply *odor insulation*, or maybe *smell insulation*? As for *sound*, I didn't find *odor* defined as an adjective.
So should one maybe say *odoriferous insulation*?
*odoriferous* is an adjective but it usually refers to something with a bad smell which isn't particularly what I want to express: odor transferred can be neutral, pleasant or not.

Usage examples:

- Thermal insulation of this hotel room is good.
- Sound insulation of this house is poor.
- Odor insulation of that room is surprisingly poor (?)

Comment: Do you mean *filtration* — for odors?

Comment: Odors are carried via air, so if you're smelling something that you shouldn't be smelling, it means that the ventilation is not good

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza yes and no, odors are similar to sound, odors can very well pass through a thin film of plastic (wrap a ripe banana in a plastic film you can smell it through the plastic), also odor can pass through a pipe which has nothing to do with ventilation (but then yes it is carried by air in that case)

Comment: @TinfoilHat no, not filtration, which is why I made the comparison with thermal and sound insulation.

Comment: @calocedrus my point on ventilation is that the room doesn't have enough air circulation, so the smells that come from other places (like your piping) *stay in the air* enough for you to smell it

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza Lack of ventilation is a cause, not a description of how the odour came to be there in the first place. How did it get there in the first place, before it's cleared by ventilation? I believe calocedrus is wanting a term [if there is one] akin to "odour-proof". *Odour-proofness* is clumsy to the point of comic; "odour insulation" is a similar structure to "sound insulation" where *odour* is an attributive noun (functioning as an adjective). Is there a better way of putting this concept?

Comment: @AndrewLeach "odour-proof" is a good find (odor-tight could work too) even though the "proofness" quality of an object isn't strictly equivalent to "insulation" and isn't used in the same way (ex a waterproof bag, tank, watch...). But one could certainly say "this room isn't odor proof" (that would likely need some extra explanation). You could put your comment in an answer even if you have nothing else better, that'll be a +1 for you!

Comment: Odors can be masked; fresh air can replace stale air. But it is questionable whether odors can actually be blocked.

Comment: @Xanne ex.: canned soup, beef or anything doesn't smell anything outside the (closed) can.  Yes, odors can be blocked (contained in the example, to use a more accurate word).

Comment: Does some form of _hermetic_ work?

Comment: Hydrogen sulphide and ammonia have perhaps the smallest molecules among odoriferous compounds. These can possibly penetrate anywhere nitrogen can. Odour-insulating then _does_ seem equivalent to making airtight (or having a top filtration system).

Comment: FWIW, if you don't like using "sound" as an adjective, there's always "acoustic" or "acoustical".  Also, thermal insulation reduces the *conduction* of heat, but not necessarily transfer through convection, etc.

Comment: thermal insulation keeps heat in. Are you looking to keep the odor in something? Need one say more?

Comment: There is an inaptness to the physical analogy, so you won't get a perfect answer without describing how the odor is prevented from migrating.  (Look at laboratory exhaust hoods and read about "capture velocity" if you think barriers or filtration are the only ways.)  Heat can be transferred by conduction (which thermal insulation is intended to inhibit) in which only energy moves, as well as other mechanisms like convection, which rely on the movement of matter.

Comment: Consider editing to include a sample sentence as required by SWR guidelines...right now it is unclear if you are looking for a noun or an adjective.

Comment: @Cascabel I had originally provided a usage example i.e. "Odor insulation of that room is surprisingly poor", can't it be consider a sample sentence?

Comment: @Cascabel I will think of more samples. As for noun or adjective (assuming you refer to the word preceding "insulation"), can "odor" - a noun - be used as an adjective as AndrewLeach mentioned (he wrote: "attributive noun functioning as an adjective")? It would be the same for "sound" in "sound insulation" I suppose (also an attributive noun?).

Comment: @Theodore right and good points. I actually talk about what you refer as physical analogy in my answer (certainly not an exhaustive one). As for how the odor migrates, I precisely wanted to convey the same general idea as in "thermal insulation", in which the nature of the heat transfer the insulation is capable of preventing/reducing isn't explicit.

Answer (score 4):

**odor proofing**

[Example](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Developments_in_Industrial_Microbiology/EksGCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=odor%20proofing&pg=PA65&printsec=frontcover) (1959) *These might be listed as follows ... 2.Odor proofing materials and articles made therefrom...*

[Example](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_United_States_Patents_Quarterly/99FKAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=odor%20proofing&dq=odor%20proofing&printsec=frontcover) (1960) *...germ, mildew, mold, odor, and fungus proofing of textiles, paper, clothing, shoe linings, blankets, mattresses, and household and personal ...*

(2018) *Furthermore, if the lid became chipped, insect and ***odor proofing would be lost***.* [Appropriate Technology in Vector Control](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Appropriate_Technology_in_Vector_Control/XJxGDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=odor%20proofing&pg=PT309&printsec=frontcover)

(1952 ) *...shipped in liners which are dirt-proof, dust-proof, odor-proof and must...* [Material Handling Engineering](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Material_Handling_Engineering/xsQlAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=odor%20proofing&dq=odor%20proofing&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Good one.  I'd suggest odorproofness if looking for the noun version.  A Google search turns up a number of references to this word being used.

Comment: I think the gerund is used when a noun is needed, similar to *soundproofing*, *waterproofing*. *sunbathing*, *fishing*.

Comment: This is probably the best choice.  It could even refer to methods that don't involve sealing.

Comment: @DjinTonic +1 this is good though already suggested (odor-proof) by AndrewLeach in an early comment above, he didn't put it in an answer.

Comment: @calocedrus. Yes, however "odor-proof" is an adjective and AndrewLeach could not come up with a noun. He wrote "Odour-proofness is clumsy to the point of comic"

Comment: @DjinTonic you're right, especially if used in the context of my example (i.e. "odor-proofing of that room ...", but from "odor proof" to "odor proofing" the jump was a breeze wasn't it? :-)

Comment: @calocedrus  "....a breeze"  I just got that ;)

Answer (score 1):

***Airtightness*** fits <strike>perfectly</strike> [per calocedrus comment I retract this word] I believe since, as has been pointed out, odors travel through air.

Presumably, airtightness comes from the word **airtight, adj**, which [Merriam- Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airtight) defines as:

> impermeable to air or nearly so, e.g. an *airtight* seal

I found this references on a company website describing one of their attic insulation services:

> Airtightness is primarily focusing on the elimination of all
> unintended gaps and cracks on the external envelope of the building.
> [[Building systems company website]](https://www.ecologicalbuildingsystems.com/post/what-airtightness)

Comment: Odors are not air.  Polyethylene film can create an airtight barrier, but some molecules (like carbon dioxide) can pass through.  (Which is why polyethylene terephthalate is used for carbonated beverages).

Comment: Good idea, but airtightness doesn't pertain only to odors. If I say "this room is airtight" one will not get it that I'm referring to odors being able to come in or out, though it could be implied.

Answer (score -1):

- **odor insulation** (simple and straightforward, read my analysis below and the conclusion)
- odor-blocking insulation could also be a close equivalent to thermal insulation but *blocking* and *insulation* seems redundant, one doesn't say heat-blocking insulation.
- odor-proof/-ing (first proposed by Andrew Leach in one of the first comments, proposed as odor-proofing in DjinTonic's answer above (+1 for this))
- odor-tight (my reply to Andrew's comment)

The topic raised interesting comments, some of which pertaining to science (unexpected, but a pleasant surprise).
So here is some further analysis, please do comment as I'm sure the topic can raise more discussion.

**Odor**

An odor is the result of the interaction between molecules having certain properties and olfactive sensors, and *their subsequent analysis/processing*. Note that these molecules may be detected in other ways such as with a chromatograph, spectrograph, etc but with such instruments they will not produce an odor.

Odors do not travel by conduction nor radiation, but by convection (the air is the carrier), they are not a form of energy. They ultimately travel by air (though other gazes may work and odor can pass through thin solids - membranes, plastic films, porous materials...)

**Thermal, heat**

Thermal pertains to heat. Heat, as sound, results from the vibration/interaction between molecules and/or atoms, it is not dependent on the chemical nature of the molecules themselves (nitrogen N2 has no odor but can transport heat or heat be created from it; at the same time, quantitatively speaking, some molecules or atoms may contribute to produce different amounts of heat depending on their nature).
Heat is a form of energy and may be used to produce work. It can be transferred by convection, radiation or conduction. Heat can be quantified.

**sound**

Sound is a vibration, carried by a gaz, a solid or a liquid, and as for odor, has be received by a sensor and be further processed/analyzed to be interpreted as a sound (but note that sounds may exist even if not received by a sensor or be processed or analyzed, there are sounds one may not perceive or be aware off, yet they can exist). Sound can't be quantified by itself (though one says loud or soft sound, these are not quantities) unless a physical quality is added: e.g. sound *pressure*. In sound pressure, sound is a noun used as an adjective.

Conclusion: despite differences (semantically, grammatically, physically, and from a chemical point of view), heat (thermal), sound and odor all share the fact that they can be isolated from a receiver. Hence **odor insulation** seems to be a logical equivalent (semantically speaking) to thermal and sound insulation, but still not the grammatically speaking equivalent to thermal insulation: from that perspective it is closer to sound insulation.

Comment: To TheDownvoter(s): Please help me to improve by commenting on why you downvoted my answer; as I wrote, "please do comment'. So please be constructive. No hard feeling for a downvoting, so don't fear any retaliation!